# android Firebase multiple providers case -how to know usr has multiple accounts?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

so i am wondering how i can determine if a user has multiple providers?  Read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking). I understand that i should call FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential (if its a facebook user) and then linkWithCredential to link the accounts.  What i dont understand is how to determine if the user even has multiple accounts.  How i understnd this process is user should already be logged in successfully into an account before calling linkWithCredential.  How would i know to even call that, i would first need to know they have multiple accounts, how ?

**UPDATE**: take a look at the web version of [firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login)

notice how they get a callback that the account credential is invalid ...

> if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential')

i want this in android sdk so i know the account already exists.  This is what i am not seeing on the android documentation. How can i know an account already exists ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the document. Linking the accounts is for different/multiple providers. A case where you have multiple logins e.g login with facebook, login with twitter, login with google etc. Let take an example to clarify this, if a user already signed your app with google id and then he uses login with facebook,  then you can link the account credentials and merge them into one user auth data.
The documents here clearly mention all this.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: How do i know the user is already signed in? I'm your example user signed in with google already. And is now currently signed in. How then can he sign in with Facebook? How would user even see the Factbook login button if he is already signed in?  Should i make an option to sign in with another provider inside the application?

Comment: i updated the question to be more clear what i need.